# Add an asterisk for a mandatory field in jsx and scss

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following label in my jsx file:

```
<label className="submit-options-any__expiry-time-label">{i18n.t('my_options.expiry_time_hr')}</label>
```

This label requires an asterisk to indicate that it is a mandatory field. And in my scss file:

```
.submit-options-any {

...  

  &__expiry-time-label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: $white-bis;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

...

}
```

I am not sure if `expiry-time-label` won't be used by other labels in my project that are not mandatory hence I don't want to change it. How could I solve this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the asterisk in the text section like this:

With ES6

```
 <label className="submit-options-any__expiry-time-label">{`${i18n.t('my_options.expiry_time_hr')} *`}</label>
```

Without ES6

```
<label className="submit-options-any__expiry-time-label">{i18n.t('my_options.expiry_time_hr')}*</label>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: ESLint: Strings must use singlequote.(quotes)

Comment: Seems like you don't have the ES6 support in your application.. I am editing my answer